# Creating a Form to POST into MySQL using PDO properly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, insert-into

I'm trying to use a PDO Wrapper Class and in general for proper security against SQL injections as good practice. Trying to learn the clean bare essentials for filling out a form to POST into MySQL.

So, at one point my form was inserting data into the MySQL table, but was doing multiple records on refresh after submit. Then I researched a cleaner way to write the processor but am now having trouble making it insert into the table. Not sure if maybe there is a discrepancy between the Processor and the "class.db.php" file?

I've searched a lot for "how-to's" having no success in a consistent answer. Trying to understand what I'm doing wrong, desiring an answer of best practice. Everything I've seen is all over the map.

Here's where I'm at:
For reference I started here first http://webdevelopingcat.com/php-mysql-tutorial-for-beginners-inserting-rows-with-pdo/

Then at top of the document I'm Including if you google, the https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/ project for a basis of class implementation.

```
<?php
include("class.db.php");
$version = "1.0.2";
$released = "December 9, 2010";
?>
```

Then a simple form within the body.

```
<?php
if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
?>

<form name='registration' action='success.php' method='POST'/>
<label for 'FName'>First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="FName" />

<label for 'LName'>Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="LName" />

<label for 'Age'>Age: </label>
<input type="number" name="Age" />

<label for 'Gender'>Gender: </label>
<input type="text" name="Gender" />

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Finally the form processor also within the body.

```
<?php
} else {
//process the form here
//
// Connect to database
$db = new db("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdodb", "root", "root");

$form = $_POST;
$first = $form[ 'FName' ];
$last = $form[ 'LName' ];
$myage = $form[ 'Age' ];
$gen = $form[ 'Gender' ];

$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ( FName, LName, Age, Gender ) VALUES ( :first, :last, :myage, :gen )";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':first'=>$first, ':last'=>$last, ':myage'=>$myage, ':gen'=>$gen ) );

}
?>
```

The MANUAL way works. Referenced culttt.com post about: prevent-php-sql-injection-with-pdo-prepared-statements

```
// Create array of data to insert
$insert = array(
"FName" => "John",
"LName" => "Doe",
"Age" => 26,
"Gender" => "male"
);
// Insert the array into the table
$db->insert("mytable", $insert);
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Are you still having issues with multiple submissions? If so, it's probably a better idea to put your form and processor into different files and use a method of POST/REDIRECT/GET: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Not at the moment. But thanks I'll make note of that. My issue is, it won't even INSERT INTO the database at all. I had it doing so at one point but the code used was terrible and cluttered. This approach seems cleaner but am having troubles making it POST.

Comment: "I'm trying to use a PDO Wrapper Class..." Uh oh. Is there anything that would preclude you from using a modern 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that provides a much more robust foundation for building applications?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @tadman I will certainly check it out. I'm desiring to learn outside the WordPress camp and make truly ground up custom Apps. This question was mostly for learning sakes, but Laravel certainly has my attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is posting to success.php, so make sure that the insert code is in the success.php file:

```
<?php
// Get POST data
$first = (!empty($_POST['FName']) ? $_POST['FName'] : '');
$last = (!empty($_POST['LName']) ? $_POST['LName'] : '');
$myage = (!empty($_POST['Age']) ? $_POST['Age'] : '');
$gen = (!empty($_POST['Gender']) ? $_POST['Gender'] : 0);

try {
    // Connect to db
    $db = new db('mysql:dbname=pdodb;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Set SQL
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable (FName, LName, Age, Gender) VALUES (:first, :last, :myage, :gen)';
    // Prepare query
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    // Execute query
    $query->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last, ':myage' => $myage, ':gen' => $gen));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Isn't db inside of the class.db.php file referencing that though?

Comment: Here's what's in the class.db.php file. `class db extends PDO {
 private $error;
 private $sql;
 private $bind;
 private $errorCallbackFunction;
 private $errorMsgFormat;

 public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $passwd="") {
  $options = array(
   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
   PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );

  try {
   parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
   $this->error = $e->getMessage();
  }
 }`

Comment: I've updated my answer to use that class. Does this display any errors now?

Comment: The FName value must not be coming through, so it's trying to insert a NULL value. I've edited my answer to make sure that FName isn't empty.

Comment: Interesting it wouldn't be allowing it through. We'll it got rid of the that error. But still no row being inserted into the table. I will say before using a form, basic PDO classes runs such as `// Create array of data to insert
$insert = array(
    "FName" => "John",
    "LName" => "Doe",
    "Age" => 26,
    "Gender" => "male"
);
// Insert the array into the table
$db->insert("mytable", $insert);` worked before trying to use a form instead.

Comment: Is your insert statement in the success.php file?

Comment: Nope nothing is in the success file other than. Success!

Comment: Okay, your form is posting to success.php, so you need to have the processing PHP in that file.

Comment: That was the issue the entire time!!!! Face Palm LOL! Both question and answers work. I did this instead of a success file. `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`

Comment: Perfect. I've updated my answer to include the filename. If it worked for you, please accept it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// Get POST data
$first = (!empty($_POST['FName']) ? $_POST['FName'] : '');
$last = (!empty($_POST['LName']) ? $_POST['LName'] : '');
$myage = (!empty($_POST['Age']) ? $_POST['Age'] : '');
$gen = (!empty($_POST['Gender']) ? $_POST['Gender'] : 0);

try {
    // Connect to db
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=pdodb;host=localhost', 'root', 'root');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Set SQL
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable (FName, LName, Age, Gender) VALUES (:first, :last, :myage, :gen)';
    // Prepare query
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    // Execute query
    $query->execute(array(':first' => $first, ':last' => $last, ':myage' => $myage, ':gen' => $gen));
    $db= null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $db= null;
}
```