# In my script SQL, row empty in the database

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to pinpoint the problem in these form scripts.

I would like to create a line in the SQL server with the data that will be inserted into the HTML form, but each time only the empty line is created without also inserting the form inputs.

HTML

```
<form action="insert2.php" method="post">

        <label for="First_name">First_name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="First_name" id="First_name">

        <label for="PASSWORD">PASSWORD:</label>
        <input type="text" name=value name="pass" id="pass">

        <label for="Emailaddress">Emailaddress:</label>
        <input type="text" name=value name="email" id="email">

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $First_name   = $_REQUEST['First_name'];
    $pass         = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $email        = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress'];
}


$servername = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users(First_name, PASSWORD, Emailaddress)
        VALUES ('$First_name', '$pass', '$email')";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: The values you are trying to insert into the table are never retrieved from the form so you are inserting exactly what are you retrieving. Nothing.

Comment: Where am I doing wrong? please help me understand
this string
$ sql = "INSERT INTO users (First_name, PASSWORD, Emailaddress)
         VALUES ('$ First_name', '$ PASSWORD', '$ emailAddress') ";

shouldn't retrieve form data in form?

Comment: Those `$First_name`,`$PASSWORD`,`$Emailaddress` are PHP Variables that you NEVER set. There is no way for your php script to just magically set variables. You will have to set them from the `$_POST[]`. Once you get that figured out, don't concatenate the values into your SQL string. Instead [bind your parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) so you don't open up a huge sql injection attack vector on your site.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, so are you advising me to create a file containing html and php?
Could you please give me some examples? I'm a beginner ...

Comment: You can retrieve the form data into a variable by writing $First_name = $_POST['First_name'];

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, to repair my previous comment. It should be $First_name = $_REQUEST['First_name'];

Comment: Hey hello! I need your help again ... if you like, go here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393500/hi-all-guys-i-need-help-for-a-project-i-am-working-on-simple-sql-php-script-th

Answer (score 0):

The posted values should be set as `$_POST['ExampleField']` not just a variable with that name.

Ex: `$First_name` should be `$_POST['First_name']`

If you look in your error logs you are likely getting undefined variable errors with the code as it is now, because `$First_name`, `$PASSWORD` and `$Emailaddress` are never defined.

Also you should avoid directly putting variables into queries like that, it opens you up to large security risks. I would recommend reading up on SQL Injection (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and binding parameters (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to see how to avoid those risks.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, so are you advising me to create a file containing html and php?
Could you please give me some examples? I'm a beginner ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, i try

Comment: This example might help point you a bit more in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27300190/4503924

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the values after a submit of some sort. You have a submit button but you'll want to give it a name (I named it submit). This code should work but you'll be vulnerable to injection attacks.

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $First_name   = $_REQUEST['First_name'];
    $pass         = $_REQUEST['PASSWORD'];
    $email        = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress'];
}

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(First_name, PASSWORD, Emailaddress)
        VALUES('$First_name','$pass','$email')";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="insert2.php" method="post">

            <label for="First_name">First_name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="First_name" id="First_name">

            <label for="PASSWORD">PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="text" name="PASSWORD" id="PASSWORD">

            <label for="Emailaddress">Emailaddress:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Emailaddress" id="Emailaddress">

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help, I tried as he advised me but the problem exists, the row is created in the database but there is no data entered in the form. There are the data "first_name", "PASSWORD", "Emailaddress".

And all day that I'm trying ..

Comment: of course, it works !! thank you very much !!!!! it's all day I feel, thanks: D

Comment: @AutomactionProgram No problem. I'm glad it worked for you. Just in case you want to do some more learning; my favourite PHP learning module for a login page is [https://www.itechempires.com/2016/06/php-login-registration-system-with-php-data-object-pdo/](https://www.itechempires.com/2016/06/php-login-registration-system-with-php-data-object-pdo/)

Comment: Okay I'll definitely take a look at it, can I always ask you for more information about my script?
Now it seems to work, but only the First_name entry saves me in the database.
I have checked all the values, but I cannot understand how it is possible.
Could you even help me understand?

Comment: @AutomactionProgram Could be duplicate names. Change your PHP page to $pass = $_REQUEST['PASSWORD']; and $email = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress']; Then change $password to $pass in the query and change $Emailaddress to $email in the query as well. I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: should I change all entries from PASSWORD -> pass? did I get it right?

Comment: @AutomactionProgram you can leave the inputs as is. However, you should change `$password = $_REQUEST['PASSWORD']` to `$pass = $_REQUEST['PASSWORD']` and change `$Emailaddress = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress']` to `$email = $_REQUEST['Emailaddress'];`. Then you need to update your query to     `$sql = "INSERT INTO users(First_name, PASSWORD, Emailaddress)
        VALUES('$First_name','$pass','$email')";`

Comment: I tried as he suggested, but unfortunately I can't solve it.
I enter the code as it is now, thanks for your patience

Comment: @AutomactionProgram I see what went wrong. The inputs say `<input type="text" name=value name="pass" id="pass">` but should be `<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">`. The email has the same problem and should be replaced with `<input type="text" name="email" id="email">`. The problem is name=value is in your password and email inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot again, I solved it in the end. I really appreciated the support you provided me, can I ask you to send me a message? I have a proposal for you. I would like to talk to you about work, if you want to contact me